# ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently não está sobrescrevendo os arquivos em uma determinada pasta

Tags: c#, arquivo-zip

Tenho uma solução de atualização de uma aplicação que utiliza a API DotNetZip (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) para manipulação de arquivos ZIP.
Um dos métodos utilizados é o de sobrescrever arquivos em determinadas pastas conforme segue abaixo.

```
 ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(file);
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
            {
                zipEntry.Extract(@"C:\IASD\CantinaEscolar", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        }
```

Onde: `@"c:\IASD\CantinaEscolar"` é o local onde serão descompactados os arquivos que estão dentro do zip `(file)`.

Só que se o diretório já possuir um arquivo com o mesmo nome do que será descompactado, a aplicação está retornando um erro referente ao arquivo já existir no diretório.

`System.IO.IOException: The file 'c:\IASD\CantinaEscola\nomedoarquivo.exe' already exists`.

Esse método  `OverwriteSilently`  não deveria sobrescrever os arquivos descompactados silenciosamente (sem solicitação de confirmação pelo usuário)?

Ou então: Existe alguma forma de forçar essa sobrescrita dentro do diretório (do tipo -f ou algo parecido)?

Se possuirem alguma outra dica de como realizar essa tarefa, ficarei grato.

Answer (score 1):

Deveria sobrescrever sim, porém imagino em dois possíveis problemas que possa impedir de sobrescrever o arquivo que você pode tentar verificar:

1. O arquivo está em uso.
2. O programa não tem permissão para excluí-lo antes de escrever um novo.

Para verificar ambos, tente fazer um teste rapidinho, pode ser no próprio "Immediate Window":

```
File.Delete(@"c:\IASD\CantinaEscola\nomedoarquivo.exe");
```

Espero que ajude...